# Remove entries of pandas multiindex if function returns false

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that receives a whole entry of a multiindex that returns true if or false for the entire index.
Hereby I am feeding several columns of the entry as a key value pair e.g.:

```
temp = cells.loc[0]
x = temp.set_index(['eta','phi'])['e'].to_dict()
filter_frame(x,20000) # drop event if this function returns false
```

So far I only found examples where people want to remove single rows but I am talking an entire entry with several hundred subentries, as all subentries are used to output the boolean.
How can I drop entries that dont fulfill this condition?

Edit:
Data sample
[image]

The filter_frame() function would just produce a true or false for this entry 0, which contains 780 rows.
The function also works fine, I just dont know how to apply it without doing slow for loops.
What I am looking for is something like this

```
cells = cells[apply the filter function somehow for all entries]
```

and have a significantly smaller dataframe

Edit2:
print(mask) of jezraels solution:
[image]

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected ouput?

Comment: So need call function per groups by first level of MultiIndex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frst call function per first level of `MultiIndex` in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) - get mask per groups, so for filtering original DataFrame use [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) for remove second level with mapping by [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html), so possible filtering in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
def f(temp):
    x = temp.set_index(['eta','phi'])['e'].to_dict()
    return filter_frame(x,20000)

mask = cells.index.droplevel(1).map(cells.groupby(level=0).apply(f))

out = cells[mask]
```

Comment: thanks this seems to do the job, the last line doesnt work for me though as python complains about different sizes for the mask and the dataframe, I suppose its because the dataframe multiindex counts both entries and subentries

Comment: @darmstadtbeste - Is added `to_numpy()` ? - It is used for match between original data and `mask` without `MultiIndex`.

Comment: yeah I added I get:
ValueError: Item wrong length 2000 instead of 1214860.

Comment: @darmstadtbeste - What is `print (mask)` ? Can you add to question? Or to my answer?

Comment: @darmstadtbeste - Can you try `mask = cells.droplevel(1).map(cells.groupby(level=0).apply(f))` ?

Comment: I get 

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Comment: @darmstadtbeste - `mask = cells.index.droplevel(1).map(cells.groupby(level=0).apply(f))` ? And then removed `to_numpy()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251337/discussion-between-darmstadt-beste-and-jezrael).